# Making SSIS smart enough not to transmit records of previous years from subsequent runs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a SSIS 2016 package that would pull records from year 2000 and store it in a partitioned table. The partition table is based on year and quarter.

The first run of package would transmit all the records. Subsequent runs I would want to run only for the current year and not consider previous years. I would I do this with my package of query.

Following is the query

```
SELECT  
    fc.financialCollectionId,
    fp.companyid,
    fd.dataitemid,
    di.dataitemname,    
    fd.dataitemvalue,
    fu.unittypevalue,
    fp.fiscalyear,
    fp.fiscalquarter,
    fi.periodenddate,
    fi.filingdate,
    rt.restatementtypename,
    fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag,
    fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag,
    conv.currencyconversionflag,
    cur.currencyname, 
    pt.periodtypename


from 
    ciqfinperiod fp 

    join ciqperiodtype pt on pt.periodtypeid = fp.periodtypeid 
    join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
    left join ciqrestatementtype rt on rt.restatementtypeid = fi.restatementtypeid
    join ciqfininstancetocollection ic on ic.financialinstanceid = fi.financialinstanceid
    inner join ciqfincollection fc on fc.financialcollectionid = ic.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqfincollectiondata fd on
        fd.financialcollectionid = fc.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqdataitemconversionrule conv on conv.dataitemid = fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqcurrency cur on cur.currencyid = fc.currencyid
    inner join ciqdataitem di on di.dataitemid= fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqfinunittype fu on fu.unittypeid =fd.unittypeid

where year(fi.periodEndDate) >=  2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as saying:

```
WHERE YEAR(fi.periodEndDate) >= YEAR(CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

You could do the first run manually and then change your statement?

Alternatively you could check the destination database to see if it's already been loaded with previous years' data (storing the result in a Boolean variable), then build your SQL statement for the data flow in a variable using an expression, e.g.,

```
"EXEC Procedure " + (DT_WSTR, 4) @[User::Year]
```

@[User::Year] (integer variable) expression:

```
@[User::PreviousDataAlreadyLoaded] ? YEAR(GETDATE()) : 2000
```

You would then use the first variable in your data flow source ('SQL command from variable').

Your procedure could then be amended to something like:

```
CREATE PROC [Procedure]
    @Year int
AS

SELECT  
    fc.financialCollectionId,
    fp.companyid,
    fd.dataitemid,
    di.dataitemname,    
    fd.dataitemvalue,
    fu.unittypevalue,
    fp.fiscalyear,
    fp.fiscalquarter,
    fi.periodenddate,
    fi.filingdate,
    rt.restatementtypename,
    fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag,
    fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag,
    conv.currencyconversionflag,
    cur.currencyname, 
    pt.periodtypename
from 
    ciqfinperiod fp 
    join ciqperiodtype pt on pt.periodtypeid = fp.periodtypeid 
    join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
    left join ciqrestatementtype rt on rt.restatementtypeid = fi.restatementtypeid
    join ciqfininstancetocollection ic on ic.financialinstanceid = fi.financialinstanceid
    inner join ciqfincollection fc on fc.financialcollectionid = ic.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqfincollectiondata fd on fd.financialcollectionid = fc.financialcollectionid
    inner join ciqdataitemconversionrule conv on conv.dataitemid = fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqcurrency cur on cur.currencyid = fc.currencyid
    inner join ciqdataitem di on di.dataitemid= fd.dataitemid
    inner join ciqfinunittype fu on fu.unittypeid =fd.unittypeid
where year(fi.periodEndDate) >= @Year
```

Comment: sorry didnt get the expression. What is MainSQLBody ? Could you breakdown and explain me the expression please

Comment: I've added more info to the answer - also note I've added a space into the expression.

Comment: My current query is in a storedproecedure and i am calling the sp from SSIS oledb source

Comment: Could you pass a parameter to it? E.g., `@Year`.

Comment: I've amended my answer to use a stored procedure instead.